# How to apply hover effect to show and hide buttons on each div?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#divHeader")) {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(this).find('#edit').show();
            $(this).find('#spandate').removeClass("datetime");
            $(this).find('#spandate').addClass("edit");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('#edit').hide();
            $(this).find('#spandate').addClass("datetime");
            $(this).find('#spandate').removeClass("edit");
        });
});
```

In my page I have 3 div with same name ("divHeader") , But it apply only first div  and skip for other two.

please tell me how to apply on all  using ID ?

Comment: what are names of those DIV's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".aClass").hover(function () {
         $(this).find('#edit').show();
         $(this).find('#spandate').removeClass("datetime");
         $(this).find('#spandate').addClass("edit");
     },
     function () {
         $(this).find('#edit').hide();
         $(this).find('#spandate').addClass("datetime");
         $(this).find('#spandate').removeClass("edit");
});
```

Create a class, the example shows "aClass", and use that. The eventhandlers for in out as shown will then find the element with id spandate within the div that is being hovered.